# bash: grep in loop does not grep

Tags: linux, bash, shell, grep

I have (probably a obvious/stupid) problem:
I want to loop over a list of paths, cut them and use the strings to grep in log files.
While every step works fine on its own and 'processed manually' results in hits - grep does not find anything when in the loop?

```
for FILE in `awk -F "/" '{print $13}' /tmp/files_not_visible.uniq`; do
  echo -e "\n\n$FILE\n";
  grep "$FILE" /var/log/PATH/FILENAME-2015.12.*;
done
```

I also tried to do a while loop as reverse exercise, but fails with the same non-result

```
while read FILE; do
  echo $FILE;
  echo $FILE | awk -F "/" '{print $13}' | grep -f - /var/log/PATH/FILENAME-2015.12.* ;
done < /tmp/files_not_visible.uniq/tmp/files_not_visible.uniq
```

So, I guess there is some systematic issue, how I handle the search string with grep?

Comment: Works here. Did you test the commands you get, when you replace `grep` with `echo grep`?

Comment: Found it: invisible character at the line end in the list of files! Lession: Always check data you get from users!

Answer (score 0):

Found it: the list of files contained invisible characters as the last character of the line! Probably the user, who send me the list of files, created it on some other OS! And I only copied -of course- the visible characters when testing by hand!

Fixed the loop by cutting the last character of a line with

```
> sed -e 's/.$//'
```

Comment: Probably carriage returns. Probably safer to use dos2unix than try to remove them manually.

Comment: yes, also my guess - lesson is for me, always check also for special characters when evaluating data from users :-/